# php previous next week based on selected date

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to create a simple weekly agenda. Here is my code:

```
$daterange = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime('2016-04-08'),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime ( '1 week' , strtotime ( '2016-04-08' ) )))
);
```

Then a simple loop:

```
foreach ($daterange as $k => $row) {
    echo  $row->format('d') ." - " . $row->format('D') . "<br>";
}
```

Produces something like:

```
08 - Fri
09 - Sat
10 - Sun
11 - Mon
12 - Tue
13 - Wed
14 - Thu
```

Which works perfectly fine, but what I need is to display dates starting from Sunday or Monday, based on first day of the week. The desired result should be:

```
10 - Sun
11 - Mon
12 - Tue
13 - Wed
14 - Thu
15 - Fri
16 - Sat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally considered bad to mix `DateTime` and `strtotime()`, `date()`, etc., so here's another solution:

```
// The question is ambiguous on this, so we'll use a
// variable to configure the preferred first weekday
$firstWeekDay = 'Sunday';

$dateTime     = new DateTime();
// If today isn't the first week day, get the last one
if ($dateTime->format('l') !== $firstWeekDay)
{
        $dateTime->modify("last {$firstWeekDay}");
}

$period = new DatePeriod(
        $dateTime,
        new DateInterval('P1D'),
        6 // Just tell PHP to create 6 (7 - the 1 start day) more dates
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Monday', '2016-04-08'));
```

You can replace `last Monday` with `next Monday`/`last Sunday`/`next Sunday`, depending on what you need. This will give you the previous/next first day of the week for current day. You could then obtain a 7 day interval, starting from this date.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting "A non well formed numeric value encountered"